# php: How to hide a list item if there is no content

Tags: php, wordpress, listitem

In php, I have a ul displayed with 3 list items as tabs. For tabs with no content, how do I keep them from displaying?

```
<div class="grid col-540 fit" id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Project Experience</a></li>

    <?php if (!empty(get('bio_publications')) { ?>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Publications</a></li>
    <?php } ?><?php endif ?>

</ul>
<div class="profile" id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <?php the_content( __( 'Read more &#8250;', 'responsive' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="project-experience" id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Project Experience</h2>
    <?php echo get('bio_project_experience'); ?>
</div>
<div class="publications" id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Publications</h2>
<?php echo get('bio_publications'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Publications tab has no content, so it should not appear]

I assumed I could do it with the if statement, but it's not working. Publications is empty for this particular ul, so the tab should not be shown.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that `get()` returns the content instead of outputting it?  Is that a native Wordpress function?  If so, can you link to the documentation for it?

Comment: Patrick, I think you may be correct, and that `get()` is a native Wordpress function. I couldn't find specific documentation and the solution from @Cesar Schrega worked perfect, so not spending any more time on this. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just really need IF conditions, but you need to get tab values 'earlier' in the code to check the conditions, something like this:

```
<?php
//get your stuff
$content = get_the_content();
$bio_project_experience = get('bio_project_experience');
$bio_publications = get('bio_publications');
?>
<div class="grid col-540 fit" id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php if ($content): ?><li><a href="#tabs-1">Profile</a></li><?php endif; ?>

       <?php if ($bio_project_experience): ?><li><a href="#tabs-2">Project Experience</a></li><?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($bio_publications): ?> <li><a href="#tabs-3">Publications</a></li><?php endif ?>

</ul>
<?php if ($content): ?>
    <div class="profile" id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <?php the_content( __( 'Read more &#8250;', 'responsive' ) ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($bio_project_experience): ?>
    <div class="project-experience" id="tabs-2">
        <h2>Project Experience</h2>
        <?php echo get('bio_project_experience'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($bio_publications): ?>
    <div class="publications" id="tabs-3">
        <h2>Publications</h2>
        <?php echo get('bio_publications'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Cesar! This worked great. Exactly what I need to hide the tab(s) when no data exists!